# How to say "if elements in the same column are the same, then calculate the average of corresponding values" in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

```
    origin_destination_country  average_delay_mins
0                       ALBANIA                0.00
1                       ALBANIA               13.68
2                       ALBANIA                0.00
3                       ALBANIA                0.00
4                       ALBANIA               79.50
...                         ...                 ...
6273                        USA                0.00
6274                 UZBEKISTAN               27.32
6275                     ZAMBIA               16.08
6276                   ZIMBABWE             1165.00
6277                   ZIMBABWE              102.97
```

How can I calculate the average of (average_delay_mins) of each country? My idea is to calculate the values corresponding to similar origin_destination_country's names, and store them in another list where there are no duplicate country names.

Comment: Use `groupby`: `df.groupby('origin_destination_country').mean()`

Comment: That is what I wanted. Many thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All thanks to Naufal_Hilmiaji and Code_Different
I just managed to find the solution and it goes like this:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'origin_destination_country': ['ALBANIA', 'ALBANIA','ALBANIA', 'USA', ...,'ZIMBABWE', 'ZIMBABWE'],
    'average_delay_mins': [0.00, 13.68,0.00,0.00,...,1165.00,102.97]
})

data = df.groupby('origin_destination_country').mean()
print(data)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code and let me know if it works.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'origin_destination_country': ['ALBANIA', 'ALBANIA','ALBANIA', 'USA', 'ZIMBABWE', 'ZIMBABWE'],
    'average_delay_mins': [0.00, 13.68,0.00,0.00,1165.00,102.97]
})

#get unique country names
list_of_countries = df['origin_destination_country'].unique()

res = []
for i in range(len(list_of_countries)):
    #get series of identical country names
    get_series = df[df['origin_destination_country'] == list_of_countries[i]]['average_delay_mins'].tolist()
    res.append(sum(get_series) / len(get_series))

print(res)
```